# Tell BoxLayout which component to stretch, and and to disallow others?

Tags: java, swing, java-8

I've got a basic swing GUI set up, including a dialog window. It looks the way I want it to, and acts the way I want it to... except that when I resize the dialog window vertically, it stretches a text field instead of the `JScrollPane` like I would like it to do.

I've found lots of advice around the web about resizing in general, but I couldn't figure out how to apply what I'd found to this specific issue.

Following is an example to replicate the behavior. I'd rather keep the `BoxLayout` managers, as I've already been through many other issues with other managers, and this setup is finally working... only with this one small remaining issue.

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;

public class ExampleDialog extends JDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExampleDialog dialog = new ExampleDialog(null, "Title", true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public ExampleDialog(JFrame parent, String title, boolean modal) 
    {
        super(parent, title, modal);
        
        
        // Top panel
        
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setText("Text");
        field.setEnabled(false);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        topPanel.add(field);
        topPanel.add(button1);
        
        
        // Middle panel
        
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
            root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(String.format("%0100d", i)));
        ExamplePanel middlePanel = new ExamplePanel(new DefaultTreeModel(root));
        
        
        // Bottom panel
        
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        
        bottomPanel.add(button2);
        bottomPanel.add(button3);
        
        
        // Content panel
        
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
        
        contentPanel.add(topPanel);
        contentPanel.add(middlePanel);
        contentPanel.add(bottomPanel);
        
        this.setContentPane(contentPanel);
        
        this.pack();
    }

    public class ExamplePanel extends JScrollPane {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public ExamplePanel(TreeModel model) {
            super();
            
            JTree tree = new JTree(model);
            
            tree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            this.setViewportView(tree);
        }
    }
}
```

Looks good:
[image: Before scaling]

Until I scale it (vertically):
[image: After vertical scaling]

Horizontal scaling works great. Can you help me figure out what I need to change?

Note, all the border stuff in the code is leftover from a coworker, and I haven't played with it much. Nor do I understand what exactly it's trying to accomplish. So I don't know if that's part of the problem, unrelated, or perhaps even accomplishing absolutely nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: I know you said you want to retain a `BoxLayout`, but a `BorderLayout` would stretch the center component as you desire.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: Thanks, @GilbertLeBlanc! I think that's done it. I just hope the manager change doesn't give me other problems like I was having with some other managers before...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment:

- BoxLayout has same space for all components.
- BorderLayout would give maximum space to the center component.
- GridBagLayout allows you to grow components indiviually. It is the most capable yet most complex one to use - but it is worth taking a look. It can replace almost all the other available layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gilbert Le Blanc's comment on the question, I swapped out a `BoxLayout` for a `BorderLayout`-- and will hope that I can fix any errors that I run into because of it!

There were a few other small changes needed-- here's the updated version:

```
// ADDED
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;

public class ExampleDialog extends JDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExampleDialog dialog = new ExampleDialog(null, "Title", true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public ExampleDialog(JFrame parent, String title, boolean modal) 
    {
        super(parent, title, modal);
        
        
        // Top panel
        
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setText("Text");
        field.setEnabled(false);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        topPanel.add(field);
        topPanel.add(button1);
        
        
        // Middle panel
        
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
            root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(String.format("%0100d", i)));
        ExamplePanel middlePanel = new ExamplePanel(new DefaultTreeModel(root));
        
        
        // Bottom panel
        
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        
        bottomPanel.add(button2);
        bottomPanel.add(button3);

        // ADDED
        JPanel bottomPanelHolder = new JPanel();
        bottomPanelHolder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanelHolder, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        bottomPanelHolder.add(bottomPanel);
        
        
        // Content panel
        
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

        // REMOVED
        //contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        // ADDED
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        contentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));

        // REMOVED
        //contentPanel.add(topPanel);
        //contentPanel.add(middlePanel);
        //contentPanel.add(bottomPanel);
        // ADDED
        contentPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        contentPanel.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.add(bottomPanelHolder, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        
        this.setContentPane(contentPanel);
        
        this.pack();
    }

    public class ExamplePanel extends JScrollPane {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public ExamplePanel(TreeModel model) {
            super();
            
            JTree tree = new JTree(model);
            
            tree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            this.setViewportView(tree);
        }
    }
}
```